# How to catch network svg images in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, firebase-storage

I've previously used the [Catched Network Image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package in my Flutter app to Catch images of types such as png and jpg. However, now I have some.svg images and I wanted to catch them so I tried to use the same method, but I got the following error:

> Exception: Invalid image data

I can show the svg directly using flutter_svg but I want to catch the image like how its done in catched network image

Is the problem with the package that it doesn't support SVG, or am I doing something wrong? if the package does not support svg then is there any alternative for that?

Here is my code for reference

```
CachedNetworkImage(

                      placeholder: (context, url) =>
                          const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      imageUrl: 'link'
                      ,fit: BoxFit.fill,

                  ),
```

Comment: There is no catching in this method. I can use that but everytime the user navigate to the screen it will download it again

Answer (score 0):

Use package: flutter_svg
[flutter_svg_package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)

```
SvgPicture.network('https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/check.svg')
```

Comment: this method provides no catching. this is to simply load it everytime the user navigate

Comment: for caching svg : https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_svg_image